# Conflict Using Firebase Crash Reporting Alongside PLCrashReporter

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting, plcrashreporter

We have an app that has been using [PLCrashReporter](https://www.plcrashreporter.org/) for a while now and although it is decently old, we have had very little issues, however now we would like to take advantage of Firebase Crash Reporting, while concurrently using our custom solution with PLCrashReporter.

I've tried this, and rather than the app crashing when it should, it freezes. I've been able to confirm that it is a conflict, because if I remove all PLCrashReporter code, Firebase Crash Reporting works fine & vise versa. I also have submitted a ticket to the Firebase team, who suggested posting here to see if anyone has a workaround.

So how about it? Any workarounds available for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, you can have only one crash reporting tool active at any given time.  This is because of the way that crashes are detected using signal handlers - there can only be one signal handler active at a time.

Android apps don't have this limitation because exception handlers can chain in sequence, as long as they perform that chaining correctly.